# Speech Recognition using oculus quest 2, any idea how to do it in Unreal Engine?

Tags: speech-recognition, unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint, unreal-engine5, oculusquest

Does anyone have any ideas how to do speech recognition for vr with unreal engine?

Are there any plugins or tutorials?

Comment: Each platform provides some form of speech recognition. There is no generic formula.

Comment: Most speech recognition services are online, and have some kind of HTTP REST API. For example, Azure, IBM Watson, Google Cloud, AWS all have a text/speech service. You need to record audio with e.g. `UAudioCaptureComponent`, and then send the PCM audio to your speech recognition service's endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

There is an offline speech recognition plugin that uses Whisper C++. Think it's based on tech from OpenAI

https://www.unrealengine.com/marketplace/en-US/product/runtime-speech-recognizer

and also on Github for latest version if the marketplace is a bit behind

https://github.com/gtreshchev/RuntimeSpeechRecognizer/wiki/1.-How-to-use-the-plugin

I've used this one with success. Fairly easy to use, and free. And as of this post, up to date with Unreal 5.3.